# Desugared recursive async method

Tags: rust, async-await, future, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write desugared recursive async method. Here is my attempt:

```
use std::future::*;
use std::pin::*;

struct TestRecursiveAsync;

impl TestRecursiveAsync {
    pub fn foo(&self, value: u32) -> Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = u32>)>> {
        let v: Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = u32> + 'static)>> = Box::pin(async move {
            if value > 0 {
                self.foo(value - 100).await 
            } else {
                value
            }
        });
        v
    }
}
```

The compiler complains with this message ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c69b5b6afb6d23e3bc0581eeb00c4f7e)):

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0759]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime
  --> src/lib.rs:8:85
   |
7  |       pub fn foo(&self, value: u32) -> Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = u32>)>> {
   |                  ----- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
8  |           let v: Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = u32> + 'static)>> = Box::pin(async move {
   |  _____________________________________________________________________________________^
9  | |             if value > 0 {
10 | |                 self.foo(value - 100).await 
11 | |             } else {
12 | |                 value
13 | |             }
14 | |         });
   | |_________^ ...is captured here, requiring it to live as long as `'static`
   |
help: to declare that the trait object captures data from argument `self`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
   |
7  |     pub fn foo(&self, value: u32) -> Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = u32> + '_)>> {
   |                                                                        ^^^^
```

So the compiler requires `&self` to have `'static` lifetime, but it has an anonymous. Is there a way to fix that?